# Intermittent starting problem 2004 Pontiac Grand Prix

Tags: starting, pontiac, grand-prix

I have a 2004 Pontiac Grand Prix that occasionally won't start. Have had the battery load tested. It is good. I've taking the ignition wire off the solenoid and tested from the battery to the wire with the ignition turned and i have 12+ volts. I have no loss of voltage from battery positive to starter positive. Three days ago it wouldn't start. It was much colder out. Today its almost 70 degrees out and it fires right up. Any suggestions? I must have started the car 25 to 35 times throughout the day today and it starts every time. I'd hate to change the starter because I don't know if that's the problem or the sound annoyed. How would one go about checking the anti-theft system or the ignition switch or maybe the neutral safety switch?

Comment: Does the starter make any noise when the car is having this issue? Do you hear a "thunk" or anything? Or is it just "turn the key and nothing happens" situation?

Comment: No it doesn't make any noise doesn't do anything. I'm just going to have to wait until it does it again and get my voltage meter out and try to find the problem I guess. Unless the next time it does it it throws some sort of security warning and then maybe I'll check out the theft deterrent system.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find out what was causing your problems? Very intermittently, when I turn the key...nothing. turn it off and try again, the car starts.

Answer (score -2):

I'd recommend cleaning the throttle body. 10$ fix that worked wonders for my 04 GT.